# IBAction addTarget:action:forControlEvents: not working when touched for the first time, otherwise fine

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am developing a calculator app and I am trying to highlight touched buttons by changing the background color. My problem is that when I touch the button for the first time, it displays the numbers but the background color does not change. But later on it works fine, just the first touch does not work at all. I appreciate any help!

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize resultLabel;

BOOL isDecimal;
NSArray *array;
NSNumber *number;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:ACbuttonOutlet, deleteButtonOutlet, plusMinusOutlet, divideOutlet, number7Outlet, number8Outlet, number9Outlet, multiplicationOutlet, number4Outlet, number5Outlet, number6Outlet, plusOutlet, number1Outlet, number2Outlet, number3Outlet, minusOutlet, number0Outlet, decimalOutlet, resultOutlet, nil];

    for(UIButton *button in array)

    {
        [button.layer setBorderWidth:0.25];
        [button.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    }

    resultLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    /*formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter setGroupingSize:3];
    [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@" "];
    number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[resultLabel.text intValue]];
    resultLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];*/

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)highlightButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(0x450);
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:239/255.0 green:232/255.0 blue:232/255.0 alpha:1]];
    NSLog(@"1");
}

- (void)resetButtonBackGroundColor: (UIButton *)sender{
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    NSLog(@"2");
}

- (IBAction)ACbutton:(id)sender  {

    [sender addTarget:self action:@selector(highlightButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [sender addTarget:self action:@selector(resetButtonBackGroundColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    isDecimal = NO;
    Method = 0;
    SelectNumber = 0;
    RunningTotal = 0;
    resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this line in viewDidLoad method into your cycle

```
for(UIButton *button in array)

    {


        [button.layer setBorderWidth:0.25];
        [button.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(highlightButton:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to work upon background color of the button . Instead toggle/change the background image of the button.